# Assigning attribute of polygon outline to most similar polygon using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, outline

I work with QGIS. I have a map with lake outlines which is basically a mosaic of three different years (2014-2016).  I also have a map with the lake outlines for each of those three years. I now want to assign the right year to each lake outline.

How can I tell QGIS to choose the most similar lake outline of the three years and then add the correlating year to the mosaic map?

Edit1: The layer of interest which I called mosaic map are just lake polygons extracted from three different maps (2014-2016) but there is no information from which map the different lakes have been extracted. Now I want to "reverse engineer" this problem.

Edit2: I have used the same code to extract the lake outlines for the maps of 2014, 2015 and 2016. Therefore, I now have 4 layers with lake outlines. One of them I want to date by using the other three layers.

Comment: Can you add some screenshots showing the data? The mosaic is rasters?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of adding sequential edits, it would be clearer if you reworded your original question with the new information. Having to cross-reference different sections makes it hard work for the reader.